# Php store cookies with utf8

Tags: php, cookies

I have been searching the web for a way to store characters like ç ' ´` ã ¨ ^ in a cookie, but i can't find a good answer! It seems that it is pretty hard to put utf8 into cookies because there would be problems with browser compatibility for example.

So i think that this problem could be solved with some conversion/encoding of text to numbers ?

I would like to store strings like:

- Fábio Linhares  >to>  12349856789134
- Praia da vitória  >to>  59768646285827
- Praça da Alegria  >to> 26458975648235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no real problem. The browser only has to store the value as bytes and send it back to the server. And whenever you have these "unusual" characters in a PHP string, this is all you need. But you should check the encoding to be sure.

Apart from that, setting the value into a cookie and reading it back should work:

```
setcookie('strange_chars', 'ç ' ´` ã ¨ ^');
```

Load via browser and then:

```
$val = $_COOKIE['strange_chars'];
```

Comment: i'am receiving caracters with ´ like this
Ã‰voraÃ‰voraÃ‰vora

Comment: does this have something to do with the fact that i am passing a post using ajax ? and then using that info to insert into the cookie..

Comment: How do you output them? Pay attention to the charset setting inside your HTML page as well.

Comment: ok, i know that if i change the page character set it works.. but i don't think i want to change the whole page to utf8...

Comment: You DO want it. Otherwise you cannot use certain characters. And by the way: Javascript is automatically using Unicode characters, and every user also can type in any Unicode character as well. Your application has to deal with it somehow.